# Rails model common validations inherited from abstract base class but unique field validations occur on subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to understand if it's possible, given two models that share some methods and fields, to put the validations that are common between the two of them in an abstract base class. Below code represents a simplified version of my situation.

There are two classes of invoice line items: sales and collections. These line items share a common field `invoice_amount` I want to validate the presence of the `invoice_amount` from an abstract base class but fields that are not common to both models get validated by the subclass.

```rb
class Collection < InvoiceLineItem
  belongs_to :invoice
  validates :c_number, :invoice_number, :invoice_date, presence: true
.
.
.
end
```

```rb
class Sale < InvoiceLineItem
  belongs_to :invoice
.
.
.
end
```

```rb
class InvoiceLineItem < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.inherited(base)
    super
    base.send(:extend, NumberFormatter)
    base.send(:commafy, :invoice_amount)
  end

  def invoice_amount
    self[:invoice_amount] || '0.00'
  end

  def export_date
    invoice_date
  end
end
```

I've tried several things to get this to work with no success. Some of my attempts included adding the following code to my InvoiceLineItem base class

```rb
  def self.inherited(base)
    base.class_eval do
      validates :invoice_amount, presence: true
    end
    super
    base.send(:extend, NumberFormatter)
    base.send(:commafy, :invoice_amount)
  end
```

and

```rb
  def self.inherited(base)
    base.class_eval do
      base.send(:validates, :invoice_amount, presence: true)
    end
    super
    base.send(:extend, NumberFormatter)
    base.send(:commafy, :invoice_amount)
  end
```

and this as described here (https://medium.com/@jeremy_96642/deep-rails-how-to-use-abstract-classes-6aee9b686e75) which seemed promising because it described exactly what I want to do however it does not work for me.

```rb
   with_options presence:true do
     validates :invoice_amount
   end
```

In all these cases the code executes without error however if I write a test like below it fails because validation succeeds!

```rb
RSpec.describe Collection, type: :model do
  it "Requires an invoice amount" do
    result = Collection.create(invoice_amount: nil, c_number: 'CUST012', invoice_number: 'INV001', invoice_date: Date.new(1999, 1,1))
    expect(result.valid?).to be false
    expect(result.errors[:invoice_amount]).to include("can't be blank")
  end
end
```

I'm not really interested in hearing answers about how it should be done using composition instead of inheritance I won't go into the details but just assume that it has to be done using inheritance. It seems like it should be possible but I'm not sure and I can't find any source on the internet that has a solution that actually works.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue, it turns out this code was working:

```rb
class InvoiceLineItem < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.inherited(base)
    super
    base.send(:extend, NumberFormatter)
    base.send(:commafy, :invoice_amount)
  end

  with_options presence: true do
    validates :invoice_amount
  end

  def invoice_amount
    self[:invoice_amount] || 0.00
  end

  def export_date
    invoice_date
  end

  def debtor_number_up_to_space
    debtor_number.split[0]
  end
end
```

the validator was using the method `invoice_amount` which was shadowing the field on the model so invoice_amount wasn't being seen as `nil` but as `0.00` thus my test validation was passing correctly.

Once I removed the `|| 0.00` I could get the test to fail.